# Split list into multiple lists based on indices

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, indexing, slice

Not sure if this has been asked, but essentially I have a `list` (let's say `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`). I'm then given another `list` of indices from which I have to split the first list (let'say [`3, 5`]). The length of this second list **can vary**.

Now, I want the output to be (in this case) `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]`.

I don't know how to do this, and thought there would be a one-liner for this, but I've searched SO and Google for ages and can't find anything :(

Thanks!

Comment: @mirandulo Thanks!!